# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable ''z" was corrupted

Tags: c++, c

I have this code:

> ```
> char z[9];
> Int_To_BCD(vInt, z);
> Buflen += sprintf(BufStr + Buflen, "(%s)", z);
> ```

And:

> void Int_To_BCD (int val, char *out) {
>
> ```
>   int i = 0;
>   int j = 0;
>   int outIndex = 0;
>   unsigned char digits[4];
>   unsigned char Digit[2];
>
>   memcpy((void*)digits, (void*)&val, 4);
>
>   for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
>     Digit[0] = (digits[i] & HIGH) / 16;
>     Digit[1] = digits[i] & LOW;
>
>     for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
>       sprintf(&(out[outIndex]), "%d", Digit[j]);
>       outIndex++;
>     }
>   }
>   if (outIndex == 0) {
>     sprintf(&(out[outIndex]), "%d", 0);
>     outIndex++;
>   }
>
>   out[outIndex] = '\0';
>
> }
> ```

In debug mode: the program run until the end of the main function and show the message:

Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'z' was corrupted

the maximun of outIndex is 8 always. and z has 8 bytes of memory. hasn't it?

What is the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Something else can be overwriting it. Check all of your arrays and loops thoroughly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you seem to take upper and lower half of the byte.

```
Digit[0] = (digits[i] & HIGH) / 16;
Digit[1] = digits[i] & LOW;
```

These are **hex** digits: they range from 0-15.

This means that if the last digit is greater than 9, `sprintf` with `%d` will print 3 characters (2 digits and `\0`) and you will have a buffer overflow.

Comment: Hey! it's posible. Thanks! I'll try with z[12] :P

Answer (score 1):

Use %c instead of %d in

```
sprintf(&(out[outIndex]), "%d", Digit[j]);
```

is it working well?

Comment: Yes it work well, I need the number, not the character. Ex:(46120000'\0')

Comment: %c say that you want to write one byte into out.